# How to find optimum configuration in php.ini on openlitespeed?

Tags: performance, wordpress, cache, performance-tuning, php.ini

I want to increase performance on pagespeed insights, but the problem is I don't know how to use all capacity of hardware on this server ! and I need your help please.

I think litespeed not using all capacitis in my server because my memory and cpu are free and performance is not so good.

Our server hardware for esxi virtual machine configuration with centos7 and openlitespeed is:
Memory: 78.83 GB
CPU: 24 vCPUs

Our software configuration is:
OS: centos 7
cms: wordpress
cache plugin: litespeed cache
and also memcache and redis enabled

I set some parameters in /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/etc/php.ini:
Please suggest me some improvement to use more resources and increase performance to load pages faster for core web vitals.

https://freeimage.host/i/screenshot-2023-11-25-00-14-58-php-7433-phpinfo.JoVaHfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using WordPress to generate pages will give you a MASSIVE win. You can still use it for maintaining the content, but use one of the many tools available off the shelf to generate static file from your CMS.

(Btw don't link content you can add here and don't post images of text)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I don't know which tool is better to generate static files, and also if I want to increase my server performance in php.ini on OLS, can you suggest me better parameters to set ?

Comment: If you can't implement the simple and best solution, then you have a *very* long journey ahead of you.